# 404/500 error on /wp-json

Tags: htaccess, rest-api

I get 500 error on wp-json.

if I try to `echo get_rest_url()` I get `example.com/wp-json`, which then gives me error 500. I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-json` to my .htaccess, which gave me 404 error instead.

I use postname as settings for permalinks. I've tried `http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp-json/v2/posts` as well, and it gives me error 500.

EDIT:
Okay, I turned on wp_debug. Now I get the error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function   register_rest_route() in /customers/0/2/1/`. So this is my new error. Any clue for this?

Comment: If you get a 500 error, you should be able to check the server's error log for the details of the error.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I got the error: Call to undefined function register_rest_route(). Any clue what that is?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use that function without first initiating it in an action? It should be done like so:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api()
{
    register_rest_route( 'route', array(
                                'methods' => 'GET',
                                'callback' => 'function',
                       ));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a .htaccess file with

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```